# Migrate data from XML to SQL Server database

Tags: c#, sql-server, xml, xslt

I have a xml file. I want to migrate its contents to a SQL Server database.

I have the columns defined in the database. Now, I want to migrate xml tags data to different columns in the database.

As I know we can write a c# code or a sql script, but what is the best possible solution and how?

Can we have any use of xslt in this?

Comment: Is it one time activity or part of business logic requirements? If one time, you can simply do this using import/export wizard in SSMS.

Comment: You should check out [XQuery support in SQL Server](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms345122%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) which has been introduced with SQL Server 2005 - it should be able to just load and parse that XML file pretty easily

Comment: I need to create a application. Its not a one tile activity. Its a part of business requirement.

Comment: please post the XML (at least part of it). Is this a flat structure (all in one table) or do you have hierarchically structured data (nested elements)? Are the attributes, elements or a mixture? You see: many open questions...